# How to compare a string with a value of an object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I want to check if a string matches another string in an array of objects.

Here's my code

```
let myArr = [{title: "fruits"}, {title: "vegetables"}];
//I want to match a string with the 'title' of the objects 

var str = "string";
if ( myArr[i].title == str) {
    //Do something 
}
```

Comment: its `let` not `Let`, and what is the value of `i` ?

Comment: Just to make this sprint even funnier, do you expect just 'true'/'false' output or index of the matching item(s) within the array or the matching object itself? Are you looking for exact or partial match?

Comment: All most all the answers here working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're clearly already using ES6, the most idiomatic way is using `Array.includes` after `map`ping the array:

```js
let myArr = [{title: "fruits"}, {title: "vegetables"}];

var str = "string";

let match = myArr.map(obj => obj.title).includes(str);

console.log(match);
```

Comment: Your are creating a copy of the array just for looking if an item is included... I would directly use `Array.prototype.some()` or `Array.prototype.find()` instead.

Comment: @jo_va that's fair criticism. But I doubt it matters unless you're going to be using an enormous array (as in thousands of objects). And I find `includes` and `map` more readable because it's clearer what you're doing, `.some` is more generic and you have to look at the details of the function passed to it to figure out what's going on. Sure in this case it's easy but it's the kind of small "mental tax" that is better to avoid.

Comment: I also voted for 'some' solution as it seems to me more concise and elegant, but, **strangely**, 'map+includes' works [faster](https://jsperf.com/map-includes-vs-some/1), which doesn't change my opinion, of course.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I'm always a bit sceptical of such tests - but I'm actually not that surprised. I expect JS engines optimise specifically for things like `.includes` - and the overhead of creating a new array with `map`, as I said, most likely only becomes noticeable with much bigger arrays.

Answer (score 5):

First things first.
Avoid the capital letter on the `Let myVariable` is just `let myVariable`.
Also consider using `const` instead of `let` for those variables that aren't going to change :)
Now, to answer your question, you can use the `some` method. Something like this:

```
const myArr = [{title: "fruits"}, {title: "vegetables"}];
const str = 'fruits';
console.log('Exist?', myArr.some((obj)=>obj.title===str));
// This will output Exist? true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let myArr = [{ title: "fruits" }, { title: "vegetables" }];
var str = "string";
if (myArr.find(a => a.title == str) != null) {
    console.log('aaa');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ES6

```js
   let myArr = [{title: "fruits"}, {title: "vegetables"}];
    
    const checkTitle = obj => obj.title === 'fruits';
    
    //check if it is found
    if((myArr.some(checkTitle))){
    //do your stuff here
    console.log("it exists, yay")}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use -

```
let match = false
myArr.forEach(function(element){
    if(element.title === str){
        match = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

read each title element of the array using for loop -->

```
let myArr = [{title: "fruits"}, {title: "vegetables"}];

let str = "string";
for(let i=0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    if (myArr[i].title === str) {
          return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe what did you change and why, to help others identify the problem and understand this answer

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) with `!!` before to turn the value to a boolean:

```js
const myArr = [ { title: 'fruits' }, { title: 'vegetables' } ];

console.log(myArr.some(({ title }) => title === 'fruits'));
console.log(!!myArr.find(({ title }) => title === 'fruits'));
```

Comment: ...too late :) posted 6 mins ago

Comment: But destructuring assignment adds certain charm

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop through the array elements and compare them with the str.

```
var myArr = [{title: "fruits"}, {title: "vegetables"}];
var str = "string";

for (i=0;i<myArr.length;i++){
if (myArr[i].title===str){
console.log(true);
}
else {
console.log(false);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using it in my code and working perfectly from me

`var fruitsObj = myArr.find(element => element.title == "fruits")`

You will get the object which contains title fruits that is 
`{title: "fruits"}` in your case.